# How can I stop my user to open my React Native app on their phone until they will not turn on their wifi or mobile data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How can I stop my user to open my React Native app on their phone until they will not turn on their wifi or mobile data? and want to show a message or notification to turn on their internet connection to open the app.

When user will try to open the app a message/Notification should show like- You are offline, please turn on your internet connection to visit the app.

If user is already connected to the internet then don't need any message/Notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rahul you should use https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo

this package, which basically exposes methods via which you can check whether wifi or data is connected or not.

```
// Subscribe
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```

here in state.isCOnnected you will get to know whether device data is turned off or not.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 1):

try `window.navigator.onLine`
to detect if the browser is online

```
if (!window.navigator.onLine) {
   alert("you are offline");
   window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of "react-native-netinfo" npm package which gives us boolean value (true / false). You can implement your logic based on this boolean value whether it is a fallback UI or you can show alert to user as "internet is not connected" something like this.
[You can learn more use this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-netinfo)